# Google sheet import range, filter via query on contain basis

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using import range using query filter on Google Sheets

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("range"),"WHERE COL1 = 'SUNBURN'")
```

I want the filtered range at the destination should also show the records of the main sheet containing `burn` or `sun` in its Col1.

In a nutshell, I want the filter to work on 'Contain' basis rather than `Exact Match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("range"),"WHERE Col1 contains 'SUN' or Col1 contains 'BURN' ")
```

Comment: Thanks for helping the beginner, Cheers.